# Why is $g_{k}$ integrable?

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $f$ be a real-valued function that is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$. For a fixed $k \in \mathbb{R}$, let $g_{k}$ be the function $g_{k}(x)=f(x+k)$ where the domain of $g$ is appropriately chosen so that $x$ is in the domain of $g_{k}$ if and only if $x+k$ is in the domain of $f$. Then $g_{k}$ is Riemann integrable on $[a−k,b−k]$ and $$\int_{a−k}^{b-k} g_{k}= \int_{a}^{b} f$$.

I've been looking at the following proof:

> Let $I= \int_{a}^{b} f$ we know that for any $\epsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ so that $|R(f,P)−I|<\epsilon$ where $P$ is any partition with $||P||<\delta$ and $R(f,P)$ is any associated Riemann sum. Let $P_{k}$ be any partition of $[a−k,b−k]$ with $||Pk||<\delta$. If $\sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{k}(t_{j})(x_{j}−x_{j−1})$ is some Riemann sum then it is equal to $\sum_{j=1}^{n} f(x_{j}+k)[(x_{j}+k)−(x_{j−1}+k)]$, but this is a Riemann sum associated with $f$ where the partition norm is less than $\delta$. Thus, $\Vert \sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{k}(t_{j})(x_{j}−x_{j−1})−I \Vert<\epsilon$, so we see that $g_{k}$ is integrable with the same value.

I was wondering how we know that $g$ is integrable from $\Vert \sum_{j=1}^{n} g_{k}(t_{j})(x_{j}−x_{j−1})−I \Vert<\epsilon$ and how do we get that $\int_{a−k}^{b-k} g_{k}= \int_{a}^{b} f$?

Comment: Just note that corresponding to a Riemann sum for $g_k$ over any partition of $[a-k, b-k] $ there is a Riemann sum of same value for $f$ over a partition of $[a, b]$ and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is precisely the definition of being integrable, with the value of the integral being $I$.

Just re-read the first line of the proof. $\int_a^b f = I$ is defined as "for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that $|R(f, P) - I| < \epsilon$ for any partition of $[a,b]$ with $\|P\| < \delta$."

The rest of the proof shows that if you start with any partition $P_k$ of $[a-k, b-k]$ with partition norm $< \delta$, then the associated Riemann sum $R(g_k, P_k)$ is within $\epsilon$ of the value $I$. This is precisely what is needed to show that $g_k$ is integrable with $\int_{a-k}^{b-k} g_k = I$.